# Exclude directories from git diff on two separate repositories

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to do a git diff between two separate repositories. Using `git diff ProjectA ProjectB` alone works, but I have to scroll through all the differences in the `.git` directory.

I've tried `git diff ProjectA ProjectB -- . ':!.git'` to exclude the `.git` directory, but I get the following error.

```
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

I've also tried `git diff --no-index ProjectA ProjectB -- . ':!.git'` but simply receive the message:

```
usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>
```

What is the correct way to git diff two different repositories while excluding certain directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of what I have to say here is in other answers and their comments, but to fill in a few blanks, emphasize a few points, and generally provide what I hope is a single, organized, useful answer:

---

Most forms of `git diff` expect to be run within a repo work tree, to compare two versions of a file (or of each of a set of files).  For each file to be compared, maybe you're comparing the work tree version against the index version, or the version in commit A against the version in commit B.

In these cases, though, you can't compare against something outside your repo (e.g. a path outside the work tree).  If you try to refer to something outside your current repo work tree, and git thinks you're using one of these forms, then it will raise an error.

There is one specific form of `git diff` that lifts this restriction:

```
git diff [--no-index] path1 path2
```

where either: (a) you include the `--no-index` option, or (b) one of the paths is outside the current repo's work tree.  In that case, git will compare two arbitrary paths on your filesystem.  But, various features of git that are tied to a repository - like comparing with historical versions - aren't accessible when using this form.

So, when you say

```
git diff projectA projectB
```

since that paths you've given are not both in a single repo work tree, git figures it has to switch to this one special form, and so it works.

But:

That one special form is pretty limited.  You only get to list the two root paths - not an arbitrary number of path specs, like when you compare versions of a file within a repo.  When you start trying to give more general `git diff` syntax, then git says "well, this isn't the filesystem-to-filesystem comparison syntax, so I can't have this path outside the work tree"... and you get your error message.

So you have two choices.

You can use a tool other than git to compare the directories.  Such a tool might have functionality for path-based exclusions.

Or, you can use git, but do the comparison within a single repo.

```
mkdir compare
cd compare
git init
git remote add ProjectA ../ProjectA
git remote add ProjectB ../ProjectB
git fetch ProjectA
git fetch ProjectB
git diff ProjectA/master ProjectB/master
```

Now git understands that you're comparing two content versions.

You can also do this by just making ProjectB a remote of ProjectA (or vice versa) and fetching so that one of the two repos has both sets of objects.  The thing to watch for is, just deleting the remote doesn't necessarily remove all of the objects fetched from the other repo.  (It definitely doesn't remove them right away.)

Comment: git fetch says: fatal: '../mxe/CGAL-4.11/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @donbright - With the available info, I can't really tell you much more than what the error message says to check.  It sounds like the path to one of your repos (the last argument to one of the `git add` commands) isn't what git expects.  For a local repo, a simple path to the repo's root should work.  You also could try a `file:` url (`file://localhost/path/to/repo`).  As the error message notes, it's also possibly a permissions issue.

Comment: I tired the "unified repo" strategy and it works fairly well.  The only drawback I am currently experiencing is that I cannot compare against different branches in project B (only `master` is available for project B, while all branches are available for project A) is there a fix for this?

Comment: Answered my own question: you need to have all branches you may be interested in checked out locally (for either project) before you do the `fetch`.  In my case the solution was to go back to project B, `git checkout <branch>` and then refetch project B

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to exclude paths when using `git diff` in this manner. If it is possible to exclude paths, the magic signature (`:!`) that you already are using in your question would perhaps be it. More info on magic signatures at [man gitglossary](https://gitirc.eu/gitglossary.html).

If it is of any help, you can diff commits of each repo by adding one as a remote of the other.

```
cd ProjectA
git remote add ProjectB ../ProjectB
git fetch ProjectB
git diff <commit-or-branch-in-ProjectA> <commit-or-branch-in-projectB>
```

When you are done diffing, you can remove the remote:

```
git remote remove ProjectB
```

---

Digging a bit deeper, it looks like when `git diff` is run with the `--no-index` option (implicitly or explicitly), it triggers a different code path. [cmd_diff](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/builtin/diff.c#L256-L470) calls [diff_no_index](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/diff-no-index.c#L236-L303) and returns early. From what I can tell, [diff_no_index](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/diff-no-index.c#L236-L303) does not call anything that parses magic pathspecs.

The magic pathspec parsing seems to happen after the abovementioned code path would have already returned. Specifically, further down in [cmd_diff](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/builtin/diff.c#L256-L470), there is a call chain [builtin_diff_tree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/builtin/diff.c#L159-L181) -> [diff_tree_oid](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/tree-diff.c#L698-L715) -> [try_to_follow_renames](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/tree-diff.c#L578-L675) -> [parse_pathspec](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/pathspec.c#L529-L615) -> [init_pathspec_item](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a4/pathspec.c#L396-L491), and this appears to be where the magic pathspec parsing happens.

Comment: What is `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` in the context of your question, @ConfusedByCode?

Comment: The root directories of two git repositories

Comment: What part of the answer are you referring to when you say `git diff ProjectA ProjectB`?

Comment: My question states that I use `git diff ProjectA ProjectB` to find the diff between two repositories. This answer says "there is no way to diff two separate repositories in the way you describe". I am asking why I am able to use `git diff ProjectA ProjectB` to do just that.

Comment: This answer also does not address my main issue, which is excluding certain directories from the diff.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. My bad; I was not aware that `git diff` had this feature. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This answer is a bit hackish, but it's a good approach nonetheless, and it avoids comparing the .git content. Further, connecting the two repos allows moving changes in between them, which is probably one of the actual goals -- after all, you wouldn't compare totally unrelated source trees, would you?

Comment: I digged a bit deeper and updated the answer to add some more detail, in case it is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you simply use `diff` instead of `git diff` to do the comparison. You can tell diff to exclude certain paths from the comparison in order to customize the output. Downside to this is that the output of `diff` and `git diff` is not exactly the same format. Usually, it's irrelevant, but in some cases that matters.